# How to create my UX portfolio

Tags: ux-designer

It as been a week of UX self teaching. I have started studying UX design on my own, by reading books and information. I am self teaching and I would like to know how I can go about creating UX portfolio for myself to show future employers?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking personal carrier advice, rather than a specific usability concept or concern. This type of question is better suited for a forum type discussion board.

Comment: There are a lot of different approaches you could take to making a UX portfolio, probably too many to list out in this venue. This post might help you get started, it covers a lot of things in depth: http://www.uxbeginner.com/minimum-viable-ux-portfolio/

Comment: I appreciate that very much. That is helpful. Vicki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I designer from web design background I had the same question as well. and still in most cases recruiters do ask for a portfolio or list of websites or apps done. For UX i believe, specially if you are in a product team it should be presented as individual case studies. If possible show screenshots from concept stage till final product or before and after screenshot. Describe what was the issues fixed or improved and what was the process or thinking behind.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a beginner and you don't have any clients yet, I think the best you can do is you could take some already implemented application which UX you think could be improved in any way and then find a way to improve it.

It could be not just web or mobile apps, but anything that you think could be improved, like a road sign, or a train ticket vending machine or whatever.

Demonstration of cases like this before-after with a careful and precise description of benefits of your solution would show your approach and the way of thinking and this is exactly what headhunters are looking for.

Apart from that it's a great way to improve yourself.

Godspeed, young one!! ;)

Comment: That was very helpful, I am going forward with that approach. I appreciate that answer LoomyBear.